# forward exports from the public_api.ts in a Angular library

Tags: angular, angular-library

I have a lib which has modules in it

```
Parent Module 
    -- SubModule 1
        ---- Src -> public_api.ts
    -- SubModule 2
        ---- Src -> public_api.ts
    public_api.ts
```

```
Root public_api.ts
export * from './SubModule 1'
export * from './SubModule 2'
```

Essentially I modularised my library and moved a bunch of code into submodules, but now want to avoid breaking changes in apps that use the lib. So i figured I can export * from the modules in the root public_api. This doesn't seem to work.

I'm not sure how to go about this. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

try renaming public_api.ts in both submodule folder to index.ts

Comment: That breaks the imports in the submodules, as I am guessing Angular doesn't look for exports in index.ts (I wasn't aware this is a thing) - reading up on this right now.

Comment: Does Angular require both public_api.ts and index.ts for this to work?

Comment: Actually when you try to import from a folder, i believe angular looks for index.ts for all exports. If you can provide me a stackblitz, maybe i can try something for you.

Comment: Do one thing, try export * from public_api.ts in your index.ts in both submodule folders.

Comment: I sort of got it to work now, I restarted the TS server in VSC and it seems ok now, i don't think index.ts was the issue. I really am confused how this suddenly works